# fetch string between special 2 characters

Tags: bash, awk, sed

**input**:

```
random abcD .and$ 5487>1.2.3.4:random fghij & 9101112
```

**output**:

```
1.2.3.4
```

**What I have done so far**:

```
sed -e 's/'>'\(.*\)':'/\1/'
```

**I have also tried**:

```
sed -e 's/>\(.*\):/\1/'
```

*note*: I can do it with awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = ">" } ; { print $2 }' | awk 'BEGIN { FS = ":" } ; { print $1 }'
```

but it's a little bit heavy, isnt it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Solution 1st:*** This simple `sed` may help you on same.

```
sed 's/.*>//;s/:.*//'  Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** Adding `awk` solution too now.

```
awk '{gsub(/.*>|:.*/,"")} 1'  Input_file
```

***Solution 3rd:*** Using another `awk` with field separator logic.

```
awk -F'[>:]' '{print $2}'  Input_file
```

***Solution 4th:*** Using another `sed` with back references logic.

```
sed 's/\(.*>\)\([^:]*\)\(.*\)/\2/'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

if there are other chars ":" and ">" in the line, and you are sure that the substring to match contain only "." and digitis [ 0 to 9 ], it will be better to use :

```
 sed "s/.*>\([0-9|.][0-9|.]*\):.*/\1/g"
```

or better :

```
 sed "s/.*>\([0-9|.]\+\):.*/\1/g"
```

or  ( to match the first one occurence ) :

```
 sed "s/.*>\([0-9|.]\+\):.*/\1/"
```

you can also use:

```
  grep -o ">[0-9|.]*:" |  grep -o "[0-9|.]*"
```

test :

```
 echo "random > abcD .and$ 5487>1.2.3.4:random : fghij >  & 9101112" |  sed "s/.*>\([0-9|.][0-9|.]*\):.*/\1/g"
 1.2.3.4

 echo "random > abcD .and$ 5487>1.2.3.4:random : fghij >  & 9101112" |  sed "s/.*>\([0-9|.]\+\):.*/\1/"
 1.2.3.4
```